# How to look for top values in a csv file per account name in python?

Tags: python, sorting, csv

Is there anyway by which I can find the top 2 values of x1 or x2 per account name and type?

My file looks like this:

```
   AccntName,Type,Value,x1,x2
   Accnt-01,A,0.001,85,1168
   Accnt-01,A,0.1814,65,664
   Accnt-01,A,11.1399,312,1861
   Accnt-01,A,12.228,55,305
   Accnt-01,A,13.3161,205,1095
   Accnt-01,B,15.0259,298,2139
   Accnt-01,B,17.9793,112,324
   Accnt-01,B,19.1451,2180,15194
   Accnt-02,A,20.3109,423,2947
   Accnt-02,A,13.3161,205,1095
   Accnt-02,A,15.0259,298,2139
   Accnt-02,A,19.0321,120,1323
   Accnt-02,B,20.3109,423,2947
   Accnt-02,B,13.3161,205,1095
   Accnt-02,B,15.0259,298,2139
   Accnt-02,B,19.0321,120,1323
```

output something like this:

```
Accnt-01,A,11.1399,312,1861 #top 2 values
Accnt-01,A,13.3161,205,1095 #for Accnt-01,A

Accnt-01,B,19.1451,2180,15194 #top 2 values
Accnt-01,B,15.0259,298,2139   #for Accnt-01,B

and so on.. for Accnt-02,A or B
```

Any suggestions will be very helpful. Thank you so much.

Comment: How are you working out the top two? Your expected output doesn't actually show the top two...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by the last two values, so I'm going to guess that you mean the sum of the two. Use the [csv](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html) library to pull the data into rows. Now, assuming that you have a list of each account, use this function to pull the top two:

```
process_list(l):
    p_l = sorted(l, key=lambda l: l[-1] + l[-2])
    return p_l.pop(), p_l.pop()
```

Answer (score 0):

What the heck, I'm bored today...

This does replicate the output you requested. It would be more 'robust' using the csv module, but I will leave that to you dear reader.

```
csv=[line.strip() for line in """\
  AccntName,Type,Value,x1,x2
   Accnt-01,A,0.001,85,1168
   Accnt-01,A,0.1814,65,664
   Accnt-01,A,11.1399,312,1861
   Accnt-01,A,12.228,55,305
   Accnt-01,A,13.3161,205,1095
   Accnt-01,B,15.0259,298,2139
   Accnt-01,B,17.9793,112,324
   Accnt-01,B,19.1451,2180,15194
   Accnt-02,A,20.3109,423,2947
   Accnt-02,A,13.3161,205,1095
   Accnt-02,A,15.0259,298,2139
   Accnt-02,A,19.0321,120,1323
   Accnt-02,B,20.3109,423,2947
   Accnt-02,B,13.3161,205,1095
   Accnt-02,B,15.0259,298,2139
   Accnt-02,B,19.0321,120,1323
""".splitlines()]

maxes={}
header=csv[0].split(',')
for line in csv[1:]:
    eles=line.split(',')
    maxes.setdefault(eles[0]+', '+eles[1]+',',[]).append(
            tuple([float(eles[2]),int(eles[3]),int(eles[4])]))

for key in maxes.keys():
    # Since you have a list of tuples, sort them to your choosing here
    maxes[key]=sorted(maxes[key],key=lambda t: t[2]+t[1], reverse=True)

for key in sorted(maxes.keys()):
    print key,'{:8}, {:6}, {:6}'.format(*maxes[key][0])
    print key,'{:8}, {:6}, {:6}'.format(*maxes[key][1])
```

Output:

```
Accnt-01, A,  11.1399,    312,   1861
Accnt-01, A,  13.3161,    205,   1095
Accnt-01, B,  19.1451,   2180,  15194
Accnt-01, B,  15.0259,    298,   2139
Accnt-02, A,  20.3109,    423,   2947
Accnt-02, A,  15.0259,    298,   2139
Accnt-02, B,  20.3109,    423,   2947
Accnt-02, B,  15.0259,    298,   2139
```

Comment: Maybe using csv module will be more robust but I can't get through with the errors that i keep receiving with the unhashble types etc. This is a great help thank you!!

Comment: Say more? Your example is just strings. An error of 'unhashable type' implies that you have a mutable data struct like a list. Just turn them into tuples (if that makes sense without seeing context..)